# How to include multiple js_include tags in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want to include multiple Nginx javaScript files (njs) in Nginx Configuration. But i am not able to add more than one js_include directive to load a file.

I have two njs files, sample1.javascript containing authorization code, sample2.javascript containing throttling logic code. I have created 2 files for modularity and readability.
Every request should go through both authorization and throttling logic, so i use below in http tag

```
http {
    js_include /path/to/njs/file/sample1.javascript;
    js_include /path/to/njs/file/sample2.javascript;
}
```

But i get error saying too many arguments for js_include directive.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `js_import` if you have njs version > 0.4.0.

I have also tried `js_include` and it seems NGINX supports just one `js_include` declaration.

From the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_js_module.html#js_include):

> The directive is deprecated since 0.4.0 , the js_import directive should be used instead.